# Ruby on Rails with Redis, I18n key-value backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, redis

i've problem with I18n key-value backend. After watch Ryan Bates screencast http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends

I'm trying to store my I18n using redis for example :

- locale: en
- key: intro.label.title
- value: "Hello World"

but my key change to **introlabeltitle** even my controller log like :
Parameters: {"commit"=>"Submit", "authenticity_token"=>"ZYoK5MMixIz9hiN8keOd9OTkKo6dBYluATYoyQDbmrY=", "utf8"=>"✓", "value"=>"Hello World", "locale"=>"en", "key"=>"intro.label.title"}

and inside the redis-cli my key change to **"en.intro\x01label\x01title"**

here is my initializer :

```
TRANSLATION_STORE = Redis.new
I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::Chain.new(I18n::Backend::KeyValue.new(TRANSLATION_STORE), I18n.backend)
```

and my controller

```
I18n.backend.store_translations(params[:locale], {params[:key] => params[:value]}, :escape => false)
```

Thank you and sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

recently i am migrating I18n solution to redis based.I have created small script which i have turned into gem i18n_redis: http://github.com/amardaxini/i18n_redis

Answer (score 0):

```
I18n.backend.store_translations(params[:locale], {:intro => {:label => {:title => params[:value]}}}, :escape => false)
```